# Not to start xAxis at zero in LineChart iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart

[image]

I have created lineChartView. Below xAxis values are displayed hours with 1 hour time interval. My graph starts at 0 and I am not able to show proper xAxis label value.

I want to put extra space in xAxis starting so that the xAxis label can proper visible.

Here is my code:

```
 func setChart(yValues: [Double], xValues: [String]) {
    chartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
    
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    
    for i in 0..<yValues.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: yValues[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }        
    let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "")
    chartDataSet.colors = [.black]
    chartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
    
    let chartData = LineChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    let chartFormatter = LineChartFormatter(labels: xValues)
    chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = chartFormatter
    chartView.xAxis.labelCount = dataEntries.count
    chartView.data = chartData
    
    chartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
    chartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    chartView.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(dataEntries.count)
    chartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 1.0, maxXRange: 3.0)
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Added.

Comment: Try to set `chartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = -1`

Comment: @KishanBhatiya It's working for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Can we add multiple dots between two xAxis values? For example, I have three values between 11 AM to 12 PM and want to display dots on a particular location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222966/discussion-between-merry-and-kishan-bhatiya).